# Can I set onCompletionListener() to an object that is an instance of the class that extends MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have implemented a class that extends MediaPlayer.

```
public class AudioPlayer extends MediaPlayer {
   private String fileName = null;
   FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;  
   private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

   // Constructor
   public AudioPlayer(Context context) 
   {    
    // Initialization
   }

   public void onPlay(boolean start)
   {
       if(start) {
        startPlaying(this.fileName);
       }else {
        stopPlaying(this.fileName);
       }
   }

   private void startPlaying(String fileName) {
       mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
       mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
       mediaPlayer.prepare();
       mediaPlayer.start();

    // mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new CompletionListener());
    }

class CompletionListener implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        // Do stuff
        }        
    }
```

When I setOnCompletionListener on MediaPlayer object inside my custom AudioPlayer class it works just fine. However I would like to set this listener on the **object created from this class** since it's used in multiple activities. Different actions should be taken in onCompletion() method therefore implementing onCompletionListener inside my custom class is pointless.
When I create an instance of my custom class in each activity where I want to use it

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(context);
```

and set on it onCompletionListener:

```
audioPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

it’s never being called. Is there a way to call onCompletionListener on my custom object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to write a method that returns MediaPlayer object and then call setOnCompletionListener() on this object:

```
public MediaPlayer getActiveMediaPlayer()
{
    if ( mediaPlayer != null )
        return this.mediaPlayer;
    else 
        return null;
}
```

and then in the activity:

```
audioRecorder.getActiveMediaPlayer().setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.d("MediaPlayer", "test");

        }
    });
```